# sqlalchemy python update a primary key with foreign key restraints

Tags: sqlalchemy, constraints, restriction

I need to change a primary key in multiple tables that also have foreign key restraints. I was thinking to either do an update or to copy the entry with an updated primary key and delete the old entry. How can I accomplish either?

Below is a minimal working set up of my tables. P and S rely on the primary key of S and S relies on the primary key of H.

I need to update the a value of ever table for one entry. I am continually limited on changing the value because of the constraints. I would rather not remove the constraints so this can be a permanent solution for later use.

```
class H(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'ch'
    a = Column(String(255), nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    other_columns = Column(String(255))

class S(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'cs'
    a = Column(String(255), ForeignKey('ch.a'), nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    sn = Column(Integer, nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    other_columns = Column(Date)
    header = relationship("H", backref=backref('cs', order_by=a, cascade='delete, all, delete-orphan'), foreign_keys='S.a')
    __table_args__ = (UniqueConstraint('a', 'sn', name='_a_sn_uc'),)

class P(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'cs_p'
    a = Column(String(255), nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    sn = Column(Integer, nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    ps = Column(Integer, nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    other_columns = Column(String(255))
    pa = relationship("S", backref=backref('cs_p', order_by=a, cascade='delete, all, delete-orphan'))
    __table_args__ = (UniqueConstraint('a', 'sn', 'ps', name='_a_sn_ps_uc'),
                      ForeignKeyConstraint([a, sn], [S.a, S.sn]),)

class F(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'cs_f'
    a = Column(String(255), nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    sn = Column(Integer, nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    fs = Column(Integer, nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    other_columns = Column(String(255))
    fa = relationship("S", backref=backref('cs_f', order_by=a, cascade='delete, all, delete-orphan'))
    __table_args__ = (UniqueConstraint('a', 'sn', 'fs', name='_a_sn_fs_uc'),
                      ForeignKeyConstraint([a, sn], [S.a, S.sn]),)
```

Comment: Honestly I am not sure if `sqlalchemy` allows you to do it, but updating a primary key is never a good idea, regardless of the implementation... Can you give some more details on the functional side? Why is it you want to update a primary key?

Comment: Hi Irnzcip, the primary key is not the typical incrementing id number. The primary key is a number description of a physical item. Since the physical item must have a unique number it was set as the primary key. This helps prevent accidental duplicate numbers and errors. The downside is when the primary key is incorrectly entered and must be changed.

Comment: What I would like to do is just copy the entry with all the children table data to the database with a new primary key. Then delete the incorrect entry and all of its children data.

Comment: Ok. Well you could have a strategy for primary keys in which you choose either an incrementing id or the key has a meaning. I've always called them  _technical_ or _functional_, but I've been browsing to find an example and in google you get more results browsing for _natural_ vs. _surrogate_. I understand your problem, and in your case, I would definitively go for a _technical_ or _surrogate_ pk. That way, the number description of the physical item can be changed by the user any time, without messing up with the database. I don't know if you have control of the model though....

Comment: I don't have control of the model. Thanks for the suggestion though. It is good to know of alternative data structuring. I will read more about natural and surrogate. I tried pulling the data through a query. Setting the data to a new variable. Changing the primary key. Adding the new data to the database. I get the error that can't change the primary key. I must not be duplicating the data correctly.

Comment: Well, if you have to do it, what I would do in your place (not really thinking about the `orm`, but about the database itself) is to (1) feth the old row, (2) create a new element copying all the content columns, (3) update the foreign keys of the related objects, (4) commit everything